# npm install vs npm install <library>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

At work we had problem that wasn't displaying icon (from rc-menu lib) for menu block

Each time when we are running

> mvn install

we are also running

> npm install

inside package json we had this library

> "rc-menu":"^5.10.0"

The way to fix it was to run

> npm install rc-menu (Inside package.json directory)

My question why this solution works?
For me it is impossible but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version must be a missmatch.

With `npm install {package_name}` you are installing the latest version. And with `npm install` you are installing version that satisfies rules of your package.json.

As far as I can see that module doesn't have 5.10.0 version at all...

`5.0.14 is the latest of 105 releases`

You can try to see the version of that module if you install it with `npm install` by typing `npm list` afterwards.

Comment: So npm install <library> ignores version inside package.json. And the issue was just fixed because we upgraded to newest? - I'm sure the first digit was 5 with the '^' sign. I can check it later if you think this will clarify more this situation

Comment: From documentation `In most cases, this will install the version of the modules tagged as latest on the npm registry.` and yes, it will bypass package.json